# why my date picker not working on bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

```
    <html>
<head>
    <title>Activity 4 - Date Compare</title>
    <link href="http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <script src="http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#date1').datepicker().on('changeDate', function (ev) {
                $(this).datepicker('hide');
            });

            $('#date2').datepicker().on('changeDate', function (ev) {
                $(this).datepicker('hide');
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST" action="">
        <br>Use this Format: <b>mm/dd/yyyy</b><br>
        Date 1: <input type="text" name="date1" id="date1"><br>
        Date 2: <input type="text" name="date2" id="date2">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

why my DatePicker are not working... please help I don't know where I fail... I don't know how to do this... please can some one help me... I even call the ID of `date1` and `date2` still not working... please can someone help me to figure out how to do this...

I want the format like this...

`mm/dd/yyyy`
`12/15/1994`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In input type use input type="date" instead of text.

I hope that might help.

Comment: where u want to get or set values of what ?
elaborate your que.

Comment: thanks I echo like this on php `<?php echo date("Y-n-j"); ?>` cause it can't understand this format `mm/dd/yyyy`